# Send TCPDF generated pdf with phpmailer

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer, tcpdf

I am generating a pdf file on the fly without saving it to the disk with:

`$attachment = $this->pdf->Output('e-tickets.pdf', 'S');`

According to `TCPDF` this should return a string containing the `pdf` file.

But sending it with `PHPMailer` results in a corrupt file:

`$mail->AddStringAttachment($attachment, 'e-tickets.pdf',  'base64', 'application/pdf');`

I tried the following alternatives (and all possible combinations):

`$attachment = $this->pdf->Output('e-tickets.pdf', 'E');`

`$mail->AddStringAttachment($attachment, 'e-tickets.pdf');`

Nothing resulted in a working `pdf` file.
The file is not empty (it has a filesize) and when I use the `D` option in `TCPDF` the file is downloaded fine.

All other topics on Stackoverflow did not help me. they are all quite old and I am guessing using an older version.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Double-check that you have valid PDF data in that string before trying to send it: `file_put_contents('e-tickets.pdf', $attachment);`. If it's OK there, we'll need to see exactly what you mean by "corrupt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself. It was a stupid mistake really

I use `$this->pdf->Output('e-tickets.pdf', 'E');` in a class.

I changed it to `return $this->pdf->Output('e-tickets.pdf', 'E');` and it solved the issue.

Fresh day, fresh look at things can help.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
$attachment = $this->pdf->Output('e-tickets.pdf', 'E');
$attachment = chunk_split($attachment);
$mail->AddStringAttachment($attachment, 'e-tickets.pdf');
```

Comment: I did, it was one of the suggested solutions in a previous question

Comment: Uhm.. I would suggest to save the PDF in a temporary file, and then add that file as an attachment.

Comment: Do not apply chunk_split at this point, you're just corrupting the data you want to send.